# Excel VBA doing a sum based on a matched cells row via formula

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to sum a set of columns based on matched cells via formula...

Basically, to get the row I am using: `=MATCH(A3,SHEETNAME!$A$1:$A$100,0)`

So what I attempted was:

```
=IF(MATCH(A3,SHEETNAME!$A$1:$A$100,0), SUM(SHEETNAME!L&MATCH(A3,SHEETNAME!$A$1:$A$100,0)&:U&MATCH(A3,SHEETNAME!$A$1:$A$100,0)), "")
```

I'm trying to make it sum the columns L:U in the matched row... what am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Match A3 from what worksheet? Surely not `SHEETNAME` as you are looking within `SHEETNAME!$A$1:$A$100`. Do you have any VBA code (that does appear to be what you are asking for)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a worksheet formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(SHEETNAME!$A$1:$A$100, A3), SUM(INDEX(SHEETNAME!L1:U100, MATCH(A3, SHEETNAME!$A$1:$A$100, 0), )), "")
```

As VBA code in UDF function:

```
Function udf_Sum_Matching_Row(rVAL As Range)
    Dim rw As Long, dTTL As Double
    With Sheets("SHEETNAME")
        If CBool(Application.CountIf(.Columns(1), rVAL)) Then
             rw = Application.Match(rVAL, .Columns(1), 0)
             dTTL = Application.Sum(.Cells(rw, 12).Resize(1, 10))
        End If
    End With
    udf_Sum_Matching_Row = dTTL
End Function
```

Syntax on a worksheet as per your example:

```
=udf_Sum_Matching_Row(A3)
```